# Propiedades de solo lectura

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework. Tengo una clase `Compra`, al poner una propiedad de solo lectura, ¿Que funcion tiene? ¿Viene hacer como una propiedad en memoria? ¿Ya no se condidera en el map que se hace con el fluent api?

Estoy trabajando con Code-First. Muestro la clase a continuación:

```
public class Compra
{
    public Compra()
    {
        this.DetalleCompras = new List<DetalleCompra>();
    }
    public int CompraId { get; set; }
    public string NumeroDocumento { get; set; }
    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }
    public int TipoComprobanteId { get; set; }
    public EnumTipoMoneda TipoMoneda { get; set; }
    public int SolicitudOrdenId { get; set; }
    public int CondicionPagoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaEmision { get; set; }
    public string GuiaRemision { get; set; }
//        public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return this.DetalleCompras.Sum(x => x.Precio * x.Cantidad); }
    }

    public virtual Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoComprobante TipoComprobante { get; set; }
    public virtual SolicitudOrden SolicitudOrden { get; set; }
    public virtual CondicionPago CondicionPago { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DetalleCompra> DetalleCompras { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PagoProveedor> PagoProveedores { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Vendría a ser el equivalente de una columna autocalculada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> una propiedad de solo lectura, ¿Que funcion tiene?

Una propiedad que dispone sólo de `get` significa que no se puede variar su valor (por la ausencia de `set`) desde dicha propiedad; sin embargo nada te impedirá cambiar su valor desde otra propiedad pública o desde dentro de la propia clase. Esto es útil para seguir los principios de [Encapsulación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)) propios de [programación orientada a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos)

> ¿Viene hacer como una propiedad en memoria?

No tiene nada que ver las propiedades o métodos que uses para acceder a datos de la clase con la representación que tenga la clase en memoria. En general, la información que forma un objeto se almacena de manera anexa (esto puede variar según el objeto y el lenguaje) y las propiedades de acceso (tanto de sólo lectura como de lectura+escritura) acceden a dicho paquete de memoria, la cantidad o tipo de métodos de un objeto no cambian cómo se almacena el objeto en memoria.

> ¿Ya no se condidera en el map que se hace con el fluent api?

No entiendo la pregunta, de todas maneras la mejor forma de averiguarlo es probándolo.

Answer (score 0):

**>>¿Ya no se condidera en el map que se hace con el fluent api?**

Desde fluent puedes indicar una propiedad que no mapea con una columna de la tabla

[Specifying Not to Map a CLR Property to a Column in the Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#1.6)

basicamente seria

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Compra>().Ignore(t => t.Total);
```

**>>¿Viene hacer como una propiedad en memoria?**

No creo que el concepto correcto sea en memoria ya que la propia entidad esta en memoria, basicamente es una propiedad calculada que en este caso trabaja con los datos de las otras propiedades

Comment: Hola, Leandro al poner la propiedad Total de solo lectura EF me manda una excepcion, no reconoce esa propiedad y la tengo mapeada, en la tabla Compra tengo una columna Total, el problema es que ya no la reconoce como una propiedad de la clase Compra, Deseo que EF si la reconozca. En el código que muestro tengo la propiedad comentada.

Comment: es que una columna de solo lectura no la debes mapear a ninguna columna en la tabla, es mas la normalizacion de base de datos menciona que esto no deberia realizarse. Las peopiedades de solo lectura debe ignorarse en el mapping